# Laravel query sum of individual column columns

Tags: php, mysql, sql, laravel, laravel-6

The query below is executed in MySQL properly, however, the same query does not execute in Laravel.

```sql
select
   SUM(g.TOTAL_WIN) AS TOTAL_WIN,
   SUM(g.TOTAL_REVENUE) AS TOTAL_REVENUE,
   SUM(g.REAL_REVENUE) AS TOTAL_REAL_RAKE,
   SUM(g.BONUS_REVENUE) AS TOTAL_BONUS_RAKE,
   SUM(g.SERVICE_TAX) as TOTAL_SERVICE_TAX 
from
   `ofc_game_history` as `g` 
   left join
      `tournament_tables` as `tt` 
      on `tt`.`TOURNAMENT_TABLE_ID` = `g`.`TOURNAMENT_TABLE_ID` 
   left join
      `tournament` as `t` 
      on `t`.`TOURNAMENT_ID` = `tt`.`TOURNAMENT_ID` 
order by
   `g`.`GAME_HISTORY_ID` desc
```

I have tried different methods shown below.

**#1**

```php
DB::select($query->selectRaw("SUM(g.TOTAL_WIN) AS TOTAL_WIN,
    SUM(g.TOTAL_REVENUE) AS TOTAL_REVENUE,
    SUM(g.REAL_REVENUE) AS TOTAL_REAL_RAKE,
    SUM(g.BONUS_REVENUE) AS TOTAL_BONUS_RAKE,
    SUM(g.SERVICE_TAX) as TOTAL_SERVICE_TAX")->toSql());
```

**#2**

```
$query = OfcGameHistory::query();
$query->from(app(OfcGameHistory::class)->getTable()." as g");
// $query->select("g.GAME_HISTORY_ID","g.MINIGAMES_TYPE_ID","g.TOURNAMENT_TABLE_ID","g.PLAY_GROUP_ID","g.TOTAL_PLAYERS","g.TOTAL_WIN","g.TOTAL_REVENUE","g.APP_RAKE_PERCENTAGE","g.STARTED","g.ENDED","tt.TOURNAMENT_NAME","g.REAL_REVENUE","g.BONUS_REVENUE","g.SERVICE_TAX");        
$query->selectRaw("SUM(g.TOTAL_WIN) AS TOTAL_WIN,SUM(g.TOTAL_REVENUE) AS TOTAL_REVENUE,SUM(g.REAL_REVENUE) AS TOTAL_REAL_RAKE,SUM(g.BONUS_REVENUE) AS TOTAL_BONUS_RAKE,SUM(g.SERVICE_TAX) as TOTAL_SERVICE_TAX");
$query->leftJoin('tournament_tables as tt', 'tt.TOURNAMENT_TABLE_ID', '=', 'g.TOURNAMENT_TABLE_ID');
$query->leftJoin('tournament as t', 't.TOURNAMENT_ID', '=', 'tt.TOURNAMENT_ID');
```

**#3**

```php
$query->select("SUM(g.TOTAL_WIN) AS TOTAL_WIN", "SUM(g.TOTAL_REVENUE) AS TOTAL_REVENUE",
    "SUM(g.REAL_REVENUE) AS TOTAL_REAL_RAKE", "SUM(g.BONUS_REVENUE) AS TOTAL_BONUS_RAKE",
    "SUM(g.SERVICE_TAX) as TOTAL_SERVICE_TAX");
```

**#4**

```
$query->addSelect(DB::raw('SUM(g.TOTAL_WIN) as TOTAL_WIN'));
```

I want individual columns summed; I don't wish to group by. This same query executes properly, but not in Laravel. Please, can anyone suggest how I can do this?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks dude to improve my question.

Comment: The error shown does not related to all those queries.. The error explains you are not allowed to mix non aggregate column with a aggregate function without `GROUP BY` which the laravel code never uses ..  Method `#2` seams to be the one which could have triggerd that error..

Comment: No, above error are related to given query, you can try with sum of column values without group by.

Comment: *"you can try with sum of column values without group by. "*  Not needed .. `SELECT SUM(..), SUM(..) FROM table_name` is allowed and will never trigger a error.. `SELECT SUM(..), table_name.id FROM table_name` will trigger that error..   It is all in the manual..

Comment: Right, By using aggregate methods, I can get sum of single column, but I want sum of 5 columns.
$query->sum('TOTAL_WIN');
working fine, But by this I have to run 5 queries individually

Comment: See [Why should I provide a Minimal Reproducible Example for a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query)